# Adding POIs/amenities from geometries_from_polygon or geometries_from_place to graph via graph_from_gdfs

Tags: networkx, geopandas, osmnx

Does someone has a function handy that adds POIs retrieved with geometries_from_polygon (or geometries_from_place) as GDF to an existing graph via graph_from_gdfs?

Basically something simple like

```
G = ox.graph_from_place(query = "<query>", network_type='all', simplify=False, retain_all=True)
pois = ox.geometries.geometries_from_polygon(<geometry>, tags = {"amenity": [<amenity_tag>]})

> simple function that generates the nodes and edges from the pois GDF ?

G2 = ox.graph_from_gdfs(pois_nodes, pois_edges, <graph_attrs>)

> merge G and G2 ?

ox.save_graph_xml(<merged_G_and_G2>)
```

I think I can just iterate through the GDF and generate the nodes/edges myself, but I'm wondering if there isn't an easier/simpler way to do this, or even an existing function I'm missing?

I'm not looking into rendering that actual graph, I'm just looking for an easy way to generate a graph XML file that includes both, the street network and some POIs and I'm using OSMX to modify that data in some ways.